# Inverting a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` that converts two `Strings` to words and then it adds the words to the map. I have it so that one key can point to multiple values. Now I'd like to make a loop that inverts the table so that all values point to keys. Don't bother with a key pointing to multiple values in the inverse.

```
Map<Word,Set<Word>> map = new HashMap<Word,Set<Word>>();

public void add(Word t, Word m) {
    if(map.containsKey(t)) {
        Set<Word> newM = map.get(t);
        newM.add(m);
    } else {
        Set<Word> newSet = new HashSet<>();
        newSet.add(m);
        map.put(t, newSet);
    }

}

public void add(String t, String m) {
    add(new Word(t), new Word(m));
}

public Dictionary inverse() {

}
```

Comment: So what is your question?  You have just told us that you would like to do something.  Have you tried doing it?  Did you encounter problems?  What were they?  Please show us the code for your attempt to compute the map inverse.

Comment: Your problem is mostly what happens when two sets in the original map contain the same word. Then when you invert it, you can't have two entries. What would you do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're facing is the very common misuse of a map. In your case you don't realy have a map. You have something vaguely similar, so you deciced to use a map. What you really have is a Set of DictionaryEntry objects with DidctionaryEntry looking something like this:

```
public class DisctionaryEntry {

    private String word;
    private Set<String> translations;

}
```

using that datastructure and adding a `addTranslation(String translation)` method to it, I think, your question becomes fairly obvious.